# Why can't a course[] object follow a pointer to a double?

Tags: java, pointers

For my java programming class, I am trying to write a program that will tell if classes conflict. So far, I have this object called `Course`. `public void init` will initialize the courses all the members noted above, then `public boolean conflict(Scanner scan)` is where we find our conflicts with schedules. And `public String toString` returns the name and the time of the course. My question is, due to the compiling error I have as noted on the attached photo, how would I set up othercourse to compare the times and get the end time considering othercourse is a Course[] (Course array) pointer?

So far, I have tried `othercourse[i].end_time = time + length / class_period * per + length % class_period;` and this sends back a symbol cannot be found compiling error.

The same goes with the if statement, `if (othercourse[i].length  course.time && course.time < othercourse[i].length)`

I was wondering how I would set up `othercourse.time` and `othercourse.length` to appropriately follow the pointers. Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Course {

  public static final int class_period = 60;
  public static final double per = 100;

  public String name; // ie: CS142, CS141, ENG 101
  public String instructor; // ie: John Mill, Bob the Fish
  public String room; // ie: 127A, 18-218, the bathroom
  public int time; // in military notation.  ie: 1030, 1600 etc
  public int length; // length in minutes.  50 means the course
  // lasts 50 minutes. 
  public double end_time;

  // name: init
  // desc: reads in entries for the members from the user
  // params: Scanner scan
  // return: void  
  // 1) for each member do steps 2-3.    
  // 2)  prompt the user to enter a value
  // 3)  read in that value and store in the member

  public void init(Scanner scan) {

      //Steps 1-3
      System.out.print("Please enter in a course name: ");
      name = scan.next();
      System.out.print("Please enter in the name of an instructor: ");
      instructor = scan.next();
      System.out.print("Please enter in the room number: ");
      room = scan.next();
      System.out.print("Please enter in the start time: ");
      time = scan.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Please enter in the length of the course: ");
      length = scan.nextInt();
    }
    // name: conflict
    // desc: returns true if this course conflicts with the parameter
    // params: Course othercourse
    // return: boolean - true if the courses conflict
    // 1) if this course and othercourse start at the same time, return true
    // 2) calculate the end time of this course ( start time + length/60*100 + 
    //      length % 60 )
    // 3) calculate the end of the othercourse
    // 4) if this course starts after other course, and starts before 
    //  the other course ends, return true
    // 5) if the other course starts after this course, and starts before
    //  this course ends, return true
    // 6) return false

  public boolean conflict(Course[] othercourse, Course course) {

    //Step 1
    if (this.time == othercourse.time)
      return true;

    //Step 2
    course.end_time = time + length / class_period * per + length % class_period;

    //Step 3
    othercourse.end_time = time + length / class_period * per + length % class_period;

    //Step 4
    if (this.time > othercourse.length && course.length < othercourse.time)
      return true;

    //Step 5
    if (othercourse.length  course.time && course.time < othercourse.length)
      return true;

    //Step 6
    return false;
  }

  // name: print
  // desc: returns a string that represents some basic info about the course 
  // params: none
  // return: String
  // 1) return a string of the format "Course " + name + " with start time " + 
  //    time

  public String toString() {
    return name + time;
  }

}
```

Comment: That syntax on Step 5 doesn't look right.

Comment: When I was writing it up here, I forgot to add the > symbol. I've tried it there but it still throws me "cannot find symbol".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first thing's first. Your method (as per the comments even) should only take one parameter, the course being compared to. You already have the current courses information in the global scope. So your method signature is as follows:

```
public boolean conflict(Course othercourse) {
```

For step 3, you need to be using the othercourse's information.

```
//Step 3
othercourse.end_time = othercourse.time + othercourse.length / othercourse.class_period 
                * othercourse.per + othercourse.length % othercourse.class_period;
```

And now, when you call the method, it's

```
othercourse[i].conflict(course);
```

In addition, anywhere you reference `course` replace it with `this` or simply remove it (i.e. `course.time` becomes `this.time` or `time`).

Comment: In my driver file I do have this. for(int i = 0; i < othercourse.length; i++) and then,        othercourse[i].conflict(Course course, Course othercourse);

Comment: Ok. Updating answer in a few.

Comment: So in my driver file, now I call this method using my array object, and then send the course object through, just like what you said and it now works.